# Print longest name in a given string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, loops, max

I wrote the following program for displaying the longest name in the given string, but the output is not as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
        
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        
        while(t--)
        {
       
            int n;
            cin>>n;
            
            string rr[n];
        
           for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
             cin>>rr[i];
           }
                   
           string max = rr[0];
            for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
            {
              if(rr[j]>max)
              {
                 max=rr[j];
                
              }
            }
        
        cout<<"Longest name in the string is:"<<max<<endl;
        }
 
    return 0;
}
```

```
2 // no of test case
6 // no of elements in string
Harsh
Gaurav
GauravMiglani
HarshAgarwal
GeeksforGeeksGeeks
Programmiz


Longest name in the string is:Programmiz
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to stack overflow. Based on way it's coded, is this from some coding contest/platform? It would be helpful if you added a link. Also, you might want to elaborate the question. It isn't clear what the "longest name" means. Also, in the example, there should be 2 test cases but only one is mentioned

Comment: Did you show the _actual_ output, or the _expected_ output?  Describe the specifics of what the program is supposed to do.  Note that as written, your program will fail to even read the second integer in the input you've shown.

Comment: `if(rr[j]>max)` ==> `if(rr[j].length() > max.length())`

Comment: @AbhayAravinda Sorry, I never used stackflow.Here is the link.  https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/display-longest-name/0/?problemType=full&difficulty[]=-2&page=1&query=problemTypefulldifficulty[]-2page1#

Comment: @paddy it's the actual output .

Answer (score 2):

Variable length arrays as in this code snippet

```
int n;
cin>>n;

string rr[n];
```

is not a standard C++ feature. Instead you should use the standard container `std::vector<std::string>`.

In this if statement

```
if(rr[j]>max)
```

you are not comparing lengths of the strings. It seems you mean

```
if( rr[j].length() > max.length() )
```

Also the variables `t` and `n` should have an unsigned integer type as for example

```
unsigned int t = 0;
//...
unsigned int n = 0;
```

Pay attention to that there is already the standard algorithm `std::max_element` that can be used instead of the manually written loop.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::vector<std::string> v( n );

//...

auto it = std::max_element( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ),
                            []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 )
                            {
                                return s1.length() < s2.length();
                            } );
 
std::cout << "Longest name in the string is: " << *it << std::endl;
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = 
    { 
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "vide", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
    };


    auto it = std::max_element( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ),
                            []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 )
                            {
                                return s1.length() < s2.length();
                            } );
                            
    
    std::cout << "Longest name in the string is: " << *it << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Longest name in the string is: three
```

That is the program outputs the first string with the maximum length. If you need to find the last string with the maximum length then use reverse iterators as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = 
    { 
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "vide", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
    };


    auto it = std::max_element( std::rbegin( v ), std::rend( v ),
                            []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 )
                            {
                                return s1.length() < s2.length();
                            } );
                            
    
    std::cout << "Longest name in the string is: " << *it << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now the program output is

```
Longest name in the string is: eight
```

Comment: hey ! thanks a lot for this ..can you suggest me some resources to upgrade my skills in cpp?. i am just an beginner.

Comment: @sumitpatil I am also a beginner in C++. I have never worked as a C++ programmer.:)

Comment: @sumitpatil First of all download the working draft of the C++ 17 and C++ 20 Standards from the internet.

Comment: is this a correct a link.   https://eel.is/c++draft/ ok.  Then next?

Comment: @sumitpatil There can be many references. For example the C++ 17 Standard Draft can be found at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf

Comment: I don't think that reading the C++ standard is the best way for a complete beginner to learn C++.  They might not have spotted the sarcasm there.

Comment: @paddy any suggestion/recommendation or course/book from you?

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup, the designer of the C++ language, has an [extensive list of resources](https://stroustrup.com/C++.html) on his website.  He also has a [book](https://stroustrup.com/4th.html) which is an excellent read.  You can probably pick one up at a library, or like anything these days order it straight to your door.